# Why is isLargeArc required?

Tags: .net, wpf

The ArcTo method of the StreamGeometryContext has a parameter named isLargeArc. I really do not see the purpose of its existence as this could be determined from the destination point, the sweep angle and sweep direction. Am I missing something? 
Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometrycontext.arcto.aspx

Comment: Have you tried both true and false with all other parameters the same and compared the output?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion as it guided me to the solution +1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effects of all the parameters is explained in detail (with figures) here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment.aspx It is for ArcSegment but the same applies to ArcTo.